# How to detect keydown Key before focusing on the control

Tags: c#

I'm using two controls on my windows form. I want to focus on the second control by pressing (for example a digit key) on the first control. But I want the pressed key in the first control to typed on the second one. How can I do it? :-S

Comment: Winforms fights you tooth and nail to stop you from doing this.  Even IMessageFilter won't work.  Keep the focus on the second control.

Answer (score 0):

When recieve keypress event in one cotrol add raise a special event created by you on which subscribed second cotrol. One time second control recieves an event, it is able to act.

EDIT

If you want more generic approach you can always use windows hooks like here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx. But I personally would try to stay in windowsforms as much as it possible.

Comment: Yes Tigran, but he should assign the event outside the KeyPress to avoid multiple assignment. aslo you have a Control.Focus() method you can use it to set the focus to the second control.

Comment: I don't say he have to subscribe inside the methid. Subscription is made in place based on design desicion, but only once.